# Trouble accessing Neo4j on Mac local network - XAMPP Apache PHP

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, php, xampp

I have a XAMPP Apache server running PHP and NEO4j on a Mac Pro/High Sierra. I am accessing a PHP page from another mac on the same network. The PHP page is loading fine but data is not being retrieved from my Neo4j install. Neo4j is still working fine on the server computer but seems to be inaccessible remotely.

I've updated neo4j.conf file uncommenting the line below without luck:

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Any suggestions about why this is happening or what to look for would be really appreciated!